# Is there a way to change folder from batch and stay there after execution?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to run a batch file from the terminal, once this batch file end its execution I want the terminal to be in the current directory of the batch file, any idea?

I want to execute a batch file and get an output like this:

```
C:\Temp> batch_file
Moving prompt to another route
C:\Folder1\Files>
```

Comment: A batch file ran from the Command Prompt inherits the current directory assigned at the time it was invoked. Unless you change the current directory within that batch file via `ChDir`/`CD` or `PushD`, it will upon completion, return to the prompt with that same directory as current. So if your current directory is `C:\Users\Ricardo` and you invoke `Desktop\test.cmd` to run the batch file located on your desktop, when it completes, your current directory will still be `C:\Users\Ricardo`. Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58560333/edit) to clarify your intent.

Comment: Thanks, I've just updated my question.

Comment: So how do you launch the batch? double click or from cmdline?

Comment: From command line. I have this batch file on a special folder added to my PATH, so I just call it from the cmd line and executes it .

Comment: so then `pushd` to the dir without `popd` and it will end in the folder you require.. for example doing from any other location `pushd "%userprofile%"` will exit ending up in your userprofile dir.

Comment: Inside `batch_file` you could use either `CD /D "yourrequiredlocation"` or `PushD "yourrequiredlocation"` at an appropriate time.

Comment: Before `batch_file.bat` exits use `CD /D "%~dp0"`. That will leave you in the location of the batch_file.bat directory.

Comment: @lit. But that would just leave the script back at where it started. OP requires it to exit from a different dir.

Comment: When I read `"I want the terminal to be in the current directory of the batch file,..."` I thought that it should be the directory where the batch file is located.

Comment: TBF, I'd originally thought of using `%~dp0` instead of `yourrequiredlocation`, but after seeing the OP invoke the script using just its name, it would only work like their output if their script was in `C:\Folder1\Files` and that in turn was added to`%PATH%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request the help by opening `cmd.exe` and running `pushd /?`:

> Stores the current directory for use by the POPD command, then
>
> changes to the specified directory.
>
> > PUSHD [path | ..]
> >
> > path        Specifies the directory to make the current directory.

Therefore it will remain in the directory you push to, until you exit the script:

if you create something like `example.cmd` in `C:\Temp` with content:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Folder1\Files"
```

It will then exit at that file location.

As a side note, to return to the folder you started in you require `popd`, in fact you need to `popd` for each `pushd`.

Answer (score 2):

Answer completely changed after getting a better understanding of the problem.

I understand that the request is

1. Command is invoked from a terminal starting in some directory such as `c:\temp`
2. The batch file `blarg.bat` is executed
3. `blarg.bat` does stuff in a differrent directory, such as `c:\temp\a\b\c`
4. The desire is for the terminal to now be in the `c:\temp\a\b\c` when the script exits

I was surprised by what impacts this....

I've been taught to always wrap the script in `SETLOCAL`/`ENDLOCAL` to keep variables localized, and it can allow *somewhat* procedural type calling.

So I started with this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

    ECHO Starting at %CD%

    CD "c:\temp\a\b\c"
    ECHO Now at %CD%
    ECHO:
    ECHO This is where other stuff would be done
    ECHO:

(ENDLOCAL
 EXIT /B 0)
```

with the expectation that this would end with the calling terminal in `"C:\temp\a\b\c"`. But it didn't.

So I removed the setlocal/endlocal wrapping.

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Starting at %CD%

CD "c:\temp\a\b\c"
ECHO Now at %CD%
ECHO:
ECHO This is where other stuff would be done
ECHO:
```

And now it gives the desired results

```
c:\TEMP>blarg.bat
Starting at c:\TEMP
Now at c:\TEMP\a\b\c

This is where other stuff would be done

c:\TEMP\a\b\c>
```

So it appears that as long as the `cd` is at the global scope it will leave the terminal at that level. However, there is risk scripting at the global scope.

Comment: Thanks, however when the execution finishes im on the same place from where I started on my terminal. I just run the `pushd` command. Imagine this `cd` and the response is `C:\ `, if i run the batch file 'test_1' which contains only a pushd to a static route, when the batchfile finishes I run again `cd ` and the response is again `C:\ `

Comment: I believe I misunderstood your question. Let me check with you. I believe you are asking, that (1)if your terminal is at C:\foobar, and (2) you run the batch file blarg.bat, (3) you want blarg.bat to change to do stuff and when it's done you want (4) for the terminal to be in a directory as set by blarg.bat. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Please enlighten me with _"the risk scripting at a global scope"_? also I suggest you try starting at `c:\temp` and `cd d:\somedir` and see what happens. Hint. From cmd do `cd /?` and `pushd /?`

Comment: True @GerhardBarnard. `cd` to a different drive doesn't do what's desired. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Risk? One of the things I recall is that variable creep happens... the variables set in the global scope last for the duration of the terminal. Sometimes this is what's wanted, but usually it's not.